# Poor USB 3 Performance with installed & encrypted Xubuntu on Verbatim Store'n'go

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, encryption

i installed a xubuntu 17.10 on a verbatim store'n'go stick. running xubunto from stick has very poor performance.
hdparm -t to this luks-encrypted partition returns a performance about 600kb/s.

when i mount the same partition into a linux booted from internal disk, i get a performance about 200-300 mb/s. (same computer, same usb 3.0 port)

there is no swap on the stick enabled and journaling is disabled.
thanks in advance for any input or help.

regards,
daniel

Answer (score 0):

hdparm's help says the `-t` option doesn't include any (sometimes considerable) filesystem overhead, like encryption, and only looks at read speeds, not writing. And since you're booting from the device it's hardly inactive, and your system is probably running all the GUI processes as well.

> -t
>    Perform  timings  of  device reads for benchmark and comparison purposes.  For meaningful results, this operation  should  be  repeated
>                 2-3  times  on  an  **otherwise  inactive system (no other active processes) with at least a couple of megabytes of  free  memory.**   This
>                 displays  the  speed of **reading** through the buffer cache to the disk
>                 without any prior caching of data.  This measurement is  an  indication  of  how fast the drive can sustain sequential data reads under
>                 Linux, **without any filesystem overhead.**  To ensure accurate measurements, the buffer cache is flushed during the processing of -t using
>                 the BLKFLSBUF ioctl.

I've only ever had terrible performance installing a Ubuntu-based system onto a USB, granted they were cheap Lexar USB's, but running a "live" ISO or a frugal install would be infinitely faster, just remember to save any new files or remaster.